# HTTPS Get request with Micropython on a ESP8266 failing

Tags: esp8266, micropython

apologies upfront for being a complete SSL noob.

I´m starting to work with Micropython and ran into a problem that with HHTPS requests. With the below code on an ESP8266MOD 12F I try to get some information from a test API, but all I get is an error.

```
import urequests as requests
import network

WIFI_SSID = "***********"
WIFI_PW = "************"


def connect_wifi(wlan, ssid, password):
if not wlan.isconnected():
    print("\nConnecting...")
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    while not wlan.isconnected():
        pass
    print("Wifi connected")
    
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
connect_wifi(wlan, WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PW)

if not wlan.isconnected():
    connect_wifi(wlan, WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PW)
else:
    url = "http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r.text)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 25, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 116, in get
  File "urequests.py", line 62, in request
OSError: [Errno 107] ENOTCONN
```

My original attempt was to get to the Telelgram Bot API so I can send Telegram messages from my IoT devices. If I use an URL for the Telelgram API in the form of

```
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot*****:***********/sendMessage?text=Klingel&chat_id=*****"
```

I get a different error which is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 25, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 116, in get
  File "urequests.py", line 60, in request
OSError: [Errno 103] ECONNABORTED
```

When changing the Coindesk URL to HTTP, everything works fine. Unfortunately the Telegram API does not accept HTTP requests.

I tried several different urequests libraries as the on e isntalles via pip seemed to be a bit dated. The one I´m currently trying I got from [github here](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/python-ecosys/urequests/urequests.py). My ESP is running the current firmware esp8266-20220618-v1.19.1 from micropython.org.

I searched the internet for 4 days now and did not find anything that helped me. Nevertheless there seem to be quite some people to managed to use SSL in this configuration. As I am a true beginner in this whole topic, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Marcus

Comment: The ESP8266 is limited in resources, so the urequests SSL / TLS support is constrained. It may be that the Coindesk and/or Telegram APIs require more specific certificate validation etc. There's a [whole section on this in the ESP8266 docs in the MicroPython website](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/general.html?highlight=tls#ssl-tls-limitations).

Answer (score 0):

After some deeper digging I found out that the problem was caused by my Adguard DNS server which blocked the Telegram API. I did not see it on my laptop because it used a different DNS server. Now that I fixed the DNS issue, I´m getting OSError -40 which seems to be a common problem with the axTLS library used in the ESP8266. At least that makes sense to me now.
Thanks Andy for the quick reply.,